# How to save current_user with nested resource CREATE action?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model-view-controller, userid

```
MissedDate.last
 id: 32,
 user_id: nil,
 routine_id: 16,
 date_missed: Thu, 19 Nov 2015 05:00:00 EST -05:00,
 created_at: Fri, 27 Nov 2015 16:57:17 EST -05:00,
 updated_at: Fri, 27 Nov 2015 16:57:17 EST -05:00,
```

How can we set the `user_id` to the `current_user` instead of `nil`?

In the **missed_dates_controller** the create action sets `@missed_date` to `routine`, which provides the `routine_id`. Or I could set `@missed_date` to `current_user`, which would provide the `user_id`, but I need both ids to be saved by the create action.

```
  def create
    routine = current_user.routines.find(params[:routine_id])
    routine.missed_days = routine.missed_days + 1
    routine.save
    @missed_date = routine.missed_dates.build(missed_date_params)
    @missed_date.save
    respond_modal_with @missed_date, location: root_path
  end
```

I'd greatly appreciate your help!

Comment: you can add `:user_id=>current_user.id` to your params hash

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand the question right than you want to set the `user_id` for your `MissedDate` record in the `create` action.

If that's right than you just have to assign the `user_id` before saving the record.

**For example:**

Your create action:

```
def create
  routine = current_user.routines.find(params[:routine_id])
  routine.missed_days = routine.missed_days + 1
  routine.save
  @missed_date = routine.missed_dates.build(missed_date_params)
  @missed_date.user = current_user   # <= Here you assign the user to the to the `MissedDate` record. Please ensure that your MissedDate `belongs_to` the User model!
  @missed_date.save
  respond_modal_with @missed_date, location: root_path
end
```

Comment: this will probably work, but the overall modeling logic is broken and will bring sea of bugs. I think TS should consider polymorphic assosatiation

Comment: I think a polymorphic association isn't the right way here however maybe an Association to the `User` model through the `Routine` from the `MissedDate` model. This can be achieved with `has_one :user, through: :routine`. But I don't know if every `MissedDate` record should have an  assigned `User` just because it has a `routine` assigned.